# I can't do first person animation

Tags: bones, faces, filmic-blender

First of all, greetings! I am trying to make an animation via Blender and using Black Plasma Studios rigs. The animation will be First Person but I am facing an error. Can you help me?[image]

If I move the face in Layout, the camera plays as I want.[image]

Camera, Face is in hardware or when I move the face everything is as I want. But if I select rigs and select Pose Mode and move the face, the camera stays still.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now the camera is child of the entire rig object, while it should be child of the head only.

To solve, select the camera, press Alt P (delete parenting > keep transform).
Then select the camera, shift select the rig, go to pose mode, select the head bone and press Ctrl P > Bone.

Comment: Thanks! i did it.